# How to get URL params in ViewHelper with Zend Framework 2

Tags: zend-framework2

I've created simple ViewHelper with http://blog.evan.pro/creating-a-simple-view-helper-in-zend-framework-2. How to get URL params in this helper? $this->params('param') works only in controllers...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the code from the blog post, you can use this code from inside the view helper:

```
$this->request->getPost('param');  // post parameter

// or

$this->request->getQuery('param'); // query parameter
```

The code from the example receives an instance of the `Zend\Http\Request` object for the current request and stores it in the property called `request` of the view helper so you can use the request property to access the Request object and information from it.

Comment: No that doesen't work, with getQuery() i can only access to params after '?' symbol, I can't get my route parameters. Any other idea?

Comment: To get route parameters you will need the mvc router object which is not available.  If you modify the constructor to inject $locator->get('Router') then you should be able to access your route parameters.

Answer (score 1):

In view helper you have to add code like this:

Module.php

```
 'factories' => array(
            'myViewHelper' => function($pm) {
                return new MyView($pm);
            },

        )
```

Now in Helper Class file your have to add following piece of code

```
public function __construct($pm) {
    $this->pluginManager = $pm;
    $this->serviceLocator = $this->pluginManager->getServiceLocator();
    $this->routeMatch = $this->serviceLocator->get('Router')->match($this->serviceLocator->get('Request'));
}
public function __invoke() {
    $params = $this->getRouteMatch()->getParams();

}
```

Here $params will return all route params in array formate.